# C++ ASCI value instead of symbol, but cast failed

Tags: c++, casting, char, ascii, tic-tac-toe

I try to write a simple "Tic, Tac, Toe" - Game for the
console. Now I'm stuck, if I want to fill the matrix with some char
like x / o I get the Asci-symbol in decimal. I tried to parse it with
char(..) again but this doesn´t work. Can anyone tell me what I do wrong? I'm thankful for every note. It doesn´t matter for this bug, conventions or other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "XO.cpp"

using namespace::std;
using mat3x3 = char[3][3];

bool win = false;

int Round = 0;

Player player1;
Player player2;


Player getCurrentPlayer()
{
    if (Round % 2) {
        return player1;
    }
    return player2;
}


mat3x3& updateMatrix( char sector, Player currentPlayer, mat3x3& matrix)
{
    switch (sector) {
        case '1':
            matrix [0][0] = currentPlayer.m_symbol;
            break;
        case '2':
            matrix [0][1] = currentPlayer.m_symbol;
            break;
        case '3':
            matrix [0][2] = currentPlayer.m_symbol;
            break;
            
        case '4':
            matrix [1][0] = currentPlayer.m_symbol;
            break;
        case '5':
            matrix [1][1] = currentPlayer.m_symbol;
            break;
        case '6':
            matrix [1][2] = currentPlayer.m_symbol;
            break;
            
        case '7':
            matrix [2][0] = currentPlayer.m_symbol;
            break;
        case '8':
            matrix [2][1] = currentPlayer.m_symbol;
            break;
        case '9':
            matrix [2][2] = currentPlayer.m_symbol;
            break;
            
            
        default:
            cout << "ungültige Eingabe.\n";
            break;

    }
    cout << sector;
    cout << currentPlayer.m_symbol << "\n";
    return matrix;
}

int main() {
    
    // Player 1 Attribut belegung
    cout << "Player 1 gib deinen Namen ein.\n";
    cin >> player1.m_playerName;
    
    cout << player1.m_playerName << " gib dein Symbol ein.( x | o )\n";
    cin >> player1.m_symbol;
    
    // Player 2 Attribut belegung
    cout << "Player 2 gib deinen Namen ein.\n";
    cin >> player2.m_playerName;
    
    cout << player2.m_playerName << " gib dein Symbol ein.( x | o )\n";
    cin >> player2.m_symbol;
    
    //  Initalisiere Matrix
    mat3x3 tttMatrix = {{1,2,3},
                        {4,5,6},
                        {7,8,9}};
    
    while (Round < 9 && win == false) {
        ++Round;

        //  Print matchfield
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << "\t";
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                printf(" %d", (char) tttMatrix[i][j] );
                if (j != 2) {
                    cout << " |";
                }
            }
            if (i != 2) {
                cout << "\n\t-----------\n";
            }
        }
        
        printf("\n\n");
        
        char choice;
        cout << "Gib die Nummer ein, wo dein Symbol plaziert werden soll.\n";
        cin >>choice;
        
      updateMatrix( choice, currentPlayer, tttMatrix);

        
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Thx

Comment: What's in the file `XO.cpp`?  What does "doesn't work" mean?  What does "failed" mean? 
 Without a [mre], we can only guess what isn't working for you.

Comment: You are using the `%d` format specifier in your `printf` call - that's telling the function to print the corresponding argument as a decimal integer. If you want the character displayed, use the `%c` format specifier.

Comment: With a little math, and the `'%'` and `'/'` symbols, you can eliminate the `switch` statement.  In general, math is faster than a `switch` statement.

Comment: You don't check if a sector is occupied before you write over it.  Try inputting the same sector number for both players.

Comment: Focus. Your issue is basically *"I get the Asci-symbol in decimal"*, right? So why does it matter what your overall program does? Focus on the issue, a single instance of unexpected output, not your entire tic-tac-toe board. Your [mre] should not need much more than the line producing the erroneous output. Maybe an additional line or two inside `main()` to define and initialize a variable to use in your output. The fact that you are creating a certain game is just background info, not really part of your question.